# If trigger is deleted SqlTableDependency won't notice

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldependency

We are using SqlTableDependency running in a windows service to monitor changes over a set of tables.

But, due to some DB processes, the triggers are being deleted. When this happens, SqlTableDependency won't notice that, so the only way to restore functionality is to restart the Windows Service, so the library can create all the objects again.

Is there any way SqlTableDependency to be able to detect that the objects needed (Triggers, Messaqes, Queues) are missing and recreate them , or raise some event or throw an exception, so the system can detect this and try to restart the service ?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have access to a well qualified DBA on Prim?

Comment: Check the windows event logs for issues, as well as, sql server logs.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK SqlTableDependency provide you some safety scripts to cleanup its necessary DB objects in case something goes wrong the those objects stuck in the DB ([check out 'Under The Hood' section in their documentation](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency#under-the-hood)).
Using those scripts you may:

1. determine a checklist of objects your specific dependency need (using internal name convention of SqlTableDependency like eg. a trigger would be 'tr_[schema]*[monitorizedTable]*[a guid from SqlTableDependency]')
2. implement check functions upon sys tables to check you checklist from point 1. is full-fill
3. perform necessary actions if checklist is not fullfill (eg. create necessary missing objects or restart the service)

That would not be a general implementation to be added to SqlTableDependency as it would probably be bound to your specific context, also you will need higher permissions on the DB for point 3., but I see that as an approach to account for your use case to have a sort of resiliency in that part of your system.

Just to provide an example that is a similar approach from one of my works using a nhibernate session (...example limited to only check trigger is there and should be enforced perhaps with regular expressions...)

```
    public bool CheckDependencyAutomationIsAwakeOnTable(string tableName)
    {
        string q = string.Format("SELECT [name] FROM sys.triggers WHERE [name] like 'tr_%_{0}_%'", tableName);

        var query = Session.CreateSQLQuery(q);

        query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<SQLTableDependecyCheck>());

        var list = query.List<SQLTableDependecyCheck>();
        return list.Count() == 1;

    }

    private class SQLTableDependecyCheck
    {
        public SQLTableDependecyCheck()
        {

        }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```